# Convert HTML content to PNG or SVG

Tags: javascript, dom, png

I am currently using [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) to convert elements on a page to an image but i would like to convert the content in the textarea to an image.

For example:
[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Carlitta87/c1dtyr15/5/)

```
<textarea> 
<div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-third w3-container w3-padding-24"><a href="/cert/default.asp"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3cert.gif" style="width:100%;" alt="W3Schools Certification"></a> </div>
    <div class="w3-twothird w3-container"><h2>W3Schools' Online Certification</h2>
        <p>The perfect solution for professionals who need to balance work, family, and career building.</p>
        <p>More than 10 000 certificates already issued!</p>
    </div>
</div>
</textarea>
```

Let me know details of the issue are clear. Would really appreciate the assistance

Answer (score 0):

HTML2canvas allows you to take a snapshot of the a DOM segment. I am not sure sure about SVG though, these scripts will be very helpful though.